# Distance unit in KNN using cross join lateral

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, knn

The underlying geometries are SRID 4326. I want to confirm whether "pma.dist" in the select clause would be a distance in meters. Here is my code:

```
SELECT 
       clusters.areaid,
       clusters.uc_name,
       clusters.missed_area_cluster_id,      
       pma."ID" AS pma_ID,
       pma.dist
FROM inter clusters
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT pma."centerPoint", pma."ID", pma."centerPoint"::geography <-> clusters.cluster_center::geography AS dist
  FROM potential_missed_areas AS pma
  where pma.status = 'approved'
  ORDER BY dist
  LIMIT 1
) pma;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, whenever the `GEOGRAPHY` data type is used for geometric measurements, the base unit of their results, as well as their respective function arguments (e.g. for `ST_DWithin`), **is *meter***!

This is true even for geodetic reference systems that use e.g. *feet* as their primary unit.

When called with `GEOGRAPHY` types as arguments, the `<->` operator calculates distances on a ***spherical*** model - for ***spheroidal*** calculations you would need to add a call to `ST_Distance`:

```
SELECT 
  clusters.areaid,
  clusters.uc_name,
  clusters.missed_area_cluster_id,      
  pma."ID" AS pma_ID,
  pma.dist
FROM
  inter AS clusters
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT
      pma."
      ST_Distance(
        pma."centerPoint"::GEOGRAPHY,
        clusters.cluster_center::GEOGRAPHY,
        TRUE -- optional, defaults to TRUE
      ) AS dist
    FROM
      potential_missed_areas AS pma
    WHERE
      pma.status = 'approved'
    ORDER BY
      pma."centerPoint"::GEOGRAPHY <-> clusters.cluster_center::GEOGRAPHY
    LIMIT
      1
  ) AS pma
;
```

---

Note that the *KNN* search is a very costly *Cross Product* operation ***if not covered by an index*** on the `CAST` to `GEOGRAPHY`, i.e.:

```
CREATE INDEX
  potential_missed_areas__geog__func_idx
  ON
    potential_missed_areas
  USING
    GIST( CAST("centerPoint" AS GEOGRAPHY) ) -- or GIST( ("centerPoint"::GEOGRAPHY) )
;
```

Comment: thanks! do both arguments across the  <-> need to be indexed?

Comment: The index driven `<->` *KNN* ordering can *never* use two indexes.

Comment: If having indexes on two columns in a join operation may be beneficial depends on the query. Generally it would be useless and ineffective to use an index on the left join item as the *driver* of a query (i.e. looping over all rows in the left join item and ask for an index lookup on the right join item each). However, if you were to add a (spatial) filter on the left join item in the scenario above, the planner may first fetch candidates from a (spatial) index on the left join item to only use this subset to drive the query and subsequently ask for index lookups on the right join item.

Comment: So: the `LATERAL` sub-query above cannot benefit from a spatial index on `inter.cluster_center`; the index driven `<->` ordering never can. If you were to add a *spatial filter* on `inter.cluster_center` in the outer `WHERE` clause, e.g. an `ST_Intersects`, then an index on `inter.cluster_center` *may* be used.

Comment: Addendum: if you were to add a spatial filter on `potential_missed_areas."centerPoint"` *inside the sub-query*, the planner will decide based on table statistics if to use the index for the filter ***or*** the `<->` ordering - never for both; an index on the same table and column can only ever be used for multiple lookups in *logical set operations* (i.e. `AND|OR`'ed value filters of the same column).